# Como optimizar un proceso que se ejecuta cada 3 segundos sin que cargue el servidor

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, twilio

Tengo la siguiente situación: estoy realizando un proceso cada 3 segundos con la función de javascript **(setInterval)** donde me conecto a una api **(twilio)**, que leo los datos y después los inserto en la base de datos.

El proceso comienza a funcionar desde el momento en que el usuario inicia sesión en el sistema y se mantiene ejecutando. Aproximadamente como la hora de estar usando el sistema, se comienza a poner lento las peticiones que le hago al servidor medianamente el navegador, lo mismo me sucede si me aumenta el numero de usuarios conectado al sitio. En cuanto detengo el proceso, el servidor se normaliza y a la hora de cargar las paginas lo hace rápido.

Mi pregunta es de que forma puedo poner a correr este proceso de que no me cargue el servidor.

A continuación les dejo el código para ver si me pueden ayudar.

Gracias.

**En el javascript:**

```
setInterval('loadnoti()', 3000);

function loadnoti() {
    $.post('index.php?c=sendsms&f=sendnoti', function (data) {
        $("#idnoti").html(data);
    });
}
```

**En el php:**

```
case 'sendnoti':

    $twilio = new Client($sid, $token);

    $messages = $twilio->messages
        ->read(array(), 20);
    //print_r($messages);

    foreach ($messages as $record) {

        if ($record->status == 'received') {

            if (substr($record->sid, 0, 2) == 'MM') {
                $media = $twilio->messages($record->sid)
                    ->media
                    ->read(array(), 20);
                foreach ($media as $records) {
                    $media = $twilio->messages($record->sid)
                        ->media($records->sid)
                        ->fetch();
                    $uriimages =  substr("https://api.twilio.com" . $media->uri, 0, -5);
                }
            }

            $datos = array(
                'sfrom' => $record->to,
                'sto' => $record->from,
                'sbody' => $record->body,
                'sid' => $record->sid,
                'status' => $record->status,
                'imagen' => $uriimages
            );
            $sen->get_smsval($record->sid, $datos);
        }
        echo $sen->get_smsnoti($sfrom, $tipo);
    }

    break;
```

Comment: La solución a tu pregunta no esta en las peticiones del lado del cliente o con javascript, lo que tienes que hacer consultar sobre SOCKETS.
Los Sockets son del lado del servidor, estos lo que hacen es que se enteran de que algo cambió en los datos y envía una notificación al navegador. Con este concepto el navegador no tiene que estar haciendo peticiones y evitas que se ralentice tu página. [Mira este vídeo para que te enteres mejor del concepto.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZEitds5Nnx4)